# How to get the specific data from an array, shown as below, in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

[Here you would see an image displaying an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k70u.png)

I'm using jquery to send data from an exsiting table, in order to save the data on it via mysql. However, I'm unable to echo or display any specific data from the array showed on the image.

This is the code I used to get the data from the table.

```js
var output = [],
row    = 0;
$('table').find('tr').each(function (index, obj) {
    output.push([]);
    var TDs = $(this).children();
    $.each(TDs, function (i, o) {
        output[row].push($(this).text());
    });
    row++;
});
```

I transformed it into an object.

```js
var jObject={};
for(i in output)
{
    jObject[i] = output[i];
}
```

Then, I turn it into a JSON object and send it to GetGastos.php

```js
jObject= JSON.stringify(jObject);
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        cache:false,
        url:"GetGastos.php",
        data:{jObject: jObject},
        success:function(server){
          alert(server);
        }
});
```

This is what I got on my php, which prints the array as shown in the image.

```js
<?php
$data = json_decode($_POST['jObject'], true);
    
foreach($data as $d){
   print_r($d);    
}
  
?>
```

(EDIT)
How would I get just the values from the second row, which is displayed as the second array with the following values: NULL, 2, 7 and 985 in the image showed before? As well as getting the individual values into variables, for example, getting NULL in $FirstVar, 2 in $SecondVar, 7 in $ThirdVar, and $985 in $FourthVar?

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: How to get the specific data, for example, just getting the second row which includes NULL, 2, 7, and 985.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and the [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selectors to exclude the first `<tr>`:

```
$('table').find('tr:not(:first-child)')...
```

**Or**

```
$('table tr:not(:first-child)')...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked.....How am I able to get the individual values into variables, for example, getting NULL in $FirstVar, 2 in $SecondVar, 7 in $ThirdVar, and 985 in $FourthVar?

Comment: I think `$data` is a numeric array, you can access its elements by using index, `$data[0]` to get the first element, `$data[1]` to get the second element, ...

Comment: Consider to accept my answer for the future readers, here is [how you can accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: It works, however, when I add a third row to the table, and echo `$data[2]` i get values concat instead of getting them indivually.....for example I have the second row NULL, 2, 7, 985: then i got a third row which includes the following: NULL, 3, 16, 976. If I print data[2], i get as a result **716**. I would like to get each value separated or to store them in another array, so I can access it for further saving options.

Comment: I can't get it, please explain more

Comment: I would like to get the values individually, for each row. For example I have the second row NULL, 2, 7, 985: then i got a third row which includes the following: NULL, 3, 16, 976. However, when I print `$data[2]`....i get two values at the same time; I get **7** from the second row and **16** from the third row, displaying the request as `716`. I would like to get the values separate...that means getting 7 in one  variable and 16 in another one. But Ithink, it'll be better to store each value in an array.

Comment: I think you don't need to transform `output` into object, just do `jObject= JSON.stringify(output);` then you will get each row in separete array: `$data[0]` will contain the second row and so on...

Comment: Still getting the same result.

Comment: Is there something I should modify in the PHP script?